How to Switch Between Multiple Firestore Databases in the same firebase app
My Firebase project contains multiple Firestore databases, and I need to switch between these databases in my code.
const response = await firestore().collection(collectionId).doc(savedId).get().then((doc: any) => {
   console.log(doc.data(), 'doc.data()');
   return doc.data();
});

This connects to the default database, but how to mention the database Id ?
I have tried to create another app instance, but even though I am not able to find any documents or articles related to switching multiple database IDs for the Firestore in react native.
In node js, I am able to switch between different databaseId within the same project.
const { Firestore } = require('@google-cloud/firestore');

var firestore = new Firestore({          
   projectId: projectId,          
   databaseId: databaseId,          
   keyFilename: keyFilenamePath
});



Install Firebase Dependencies:

First, ensure you have the Firebase dependencies installed in your React Native project:
npm install @react-native-firebase/app @react-native-firebase/firestore


Configure Multiple Firebase Apps:

In your Firebase project, create different configurations for each Firestore database you want to use. Each configuration should include apiKey, authDomain, projectId, storageBucket, messagingSenderId, and appId.

Initialize Multiple Firebase Apps:

Initialize multiple Firebase app instances with their respective configurations.
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig1 = {
  apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY_1',
  authDomain: 'YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN_1',
  projectId: 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID_1',
  storageBucket: 'YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET_1',
  messagingSenderId: 'YOUR_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID_1',
  appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID_1',
};

const firebaseConfig2 = {
  apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY_2',
  authDomain: 'YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN_2',
  projectId: 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID_2',
  storageBucket: 'YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET_2',
  messagingSenderId: 'YOUR_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID_2',
  appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID_2',
};

// Initialize the default app
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig1);
}

// Initialize secondary app
const secondaryApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig2, 'secondary');


Access Firestore Instances:

Access Firestore instances from each app instance.
const firestoreDefault = firebase.firestore();
const firestoreSecondary = secondaryApp.firestore();


Switch Between Firestore Databases:

Use the respective Firestore instance depending on which database you need to access.
const useDefaultDatabase = true; // Change this flag to switch databases

const firestore = useDefaultDatabase ? firestoreDefault : firestoreSecondary;

// Example usage
firestore.collection('your-collection').get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => {
      console.log(documentSnapshot.data());
    });
  });

Example Component
Here's an example component that demonstrates switching between two Firestore databases:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
import '@react-native-firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig1 = {
  // Your first Firebase configuration
};

const firebaseConfig2 = {
  // Your second Firebase configuration
};

// Initialize the default app
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig1);
}

// Initialize secondary app
const secondaryApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig2, 'secondary');

// Firestore instances
const firestoreDefault = firebase.firestore();
const firestoreSecondary = secondaryApp.firestore();

const FirestoreSwitcher = () => {
  const [useDefaultDatabase, setUseDefaultDatabase] = useState(true);
  const firestore = useDefaultDatabase ? firestoreDefault : firestoreSecondary;

  const fetchData = async () => {
    const snapshot = await firestore.collection('your-collection').get();
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.data());
    });
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Switch Database" onPress={() => setUseDefaultDatabase(!useDefaultDatabase)} />
      <Button title="Fetch Data" onPress={fetchData} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default FirestoreSwitcher;


In my use case, I am connecting with different firestore database in the same firebase app.

You can use different configurations based on this
const firebaseConfig1 = {
apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY_1',
authDomain: 'YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN_1',
projectId: 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID_1',
storageBucket: 'YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET_1',
messagingSenderId: 'YOUR_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID_1',
appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID_1',
};
const firebaseConfig2 = {
apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY_2',
authDomain: 'YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN_2',
projectId: 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID_2',
storageBucket: 'YOUR_STORAGE_BUCKET_2',
messagingSenderId: 'YOUR_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID_2',
appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID_2',
};

In my use case, it is the same app, all the configuration is the same, there will be no change in the configuration, I am connecting to the firestore app, not to a different app, same firebase app, all the configuration will be the same, in the config there is no any specific specification to be mentioned for cloud firestore in the config, In the node js I am able to mention the firestore database ID, but in the client SDK for React Native there is no such option.

@HariKarthikkeyyan, did you manage to achieve this?

To switch between multiple Firestore databases in the same Firebase app, you can set the database ID when instantiating the Firestore client.
Each Firestore database is identified by a unique database ID, which defaults to (default) if unspecified.
Here’s how you can do it for a database named "prod-db":
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

// or how your firebase library imports it, eg
// import { getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

// Then, initialize Cloud Firestore and get a reference to the "prod-db" Firestore database
const db = getFirestore("prod-db");

Replace "prod-db" with the ID of your desired database.
Be sure to update to the latest Firebase Client SDKs and Google API Client Libraries.
